# C++ bitset with if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, binary, bitset

I was wondering if there is anyway to use specific range of bits with if statement.
im using a fpga to send 8bits binary data over usb to pc. each transaction has 3x 8 bits packets. in each packet first four bits are generated by outside module and i want to send control data in the last four bits.
  =>  
usb interface accepts data as integers and i've got bitset function to convert integers to 8bit binary. i want to use last four bits to use with if statements. is there any way i can do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want to extract bits and what do you mean by using `if`? -- The question is unclear.

Comment: Just `and` the byte with a bitmask? E.g., `x & 0x0f`.

Comment: sorry if its unclear. when i receive an integer via USB i want to convert it to binary, read the first four bits(left most) as data, and the last four bits to decide what to do with it. i've programmed fpga to generate control signals and concat them to send with each 8bit packet

Comment: i guess im really bad at this jeff. bitmask? is that a function?

Comment: You can use `std::bitset` or something called bitmasking (google it) to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `unsigned char` as input:

```
void foo(uint8_t x) {
  uint8_t top4    = x >> 4;  // moves top 4 bits down by 4 positions
  uint8_t bottom4 = x & 0x0f; // zeros out top 4 bits, leaving bottom 4
}
```

This will work with `int`, `short`, etc., types as well, but you would need to `&`-mask the `top` results too to strip away the unwanted high bits there.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please upvote/accept if it does the trick.

Comment: WoW. spot on jeff. if anyone interested jeff's function accepts an integer(up to 256), convert it to binary 8bit value and assignes 4 MSBs and 4 LSBs to top4, and bottom4 variables. i tried it and it works!!